# Trace VirtualProtect calls from other applications

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel32

On Windows Server 2008, I have an instance where someone is writing to the instruction memory of applications. Someone writes mostly zero's interspersed with a different sentinel byte every 16 to 32 bytes with no pattern. I'm pretty sure that in order to write to the instruction memory, someone would have to call `VirtualProtect`. I'm also pretty certain it is another application (perhaps virus scanner).

Is there a way to trace kernel calls to `VirtualProtect`?
Is there another way of finding out who might be unlocking and/or writing to the instruction space?

I've looked at `WinDbg` and `Performance Monitor`

Comment: Use a debugger.  Set a breakpoint on {,,ntdll.dll}_NtProtectVirtualMemory@20

Comment: But I need to break/trace for the system. I need to find out which exe is calling VirtualProtect.

Comment: Another EXE calling VirtualProtect() would be pointless, it can only change its own pages.  If it is not DLL injection then you got a much bigger problem.  Reinstall.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is `VirtualProtectEx`. Debuggers use this to set debug exception instructions. So it certainly can and is done. But in my case it is doing some bad stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what processes are calling [VirtualProtectEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex), You would need to inject a DLL into every running process and hook [VirtualProtectEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex)  You can then log all the results.

You can use the [AppInit DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/secure-boot-and-appinit-dlls) mechanism to do this, which makes every process load the DLL your specify.  For easy hooking you can use [MS Detours](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours).